# Why is a catch being triggered if my Fetch is succesful?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing with component where on component did mount, it gets some data from an api,

I am mocking the response to be succesful, but still the catch block is being triggered, i think it shouldnt.

and i get this error:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
          at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (C:\Users\jorge\Documents\testingreact\React-Testing-For-Beginners\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:436:16)
```

This is my component:

```
class MoviesList extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    movies: [],
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=APIKEY&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1',
      )
      const movies = await res.json();
      if (movies.success) {
        this.setState({
          movies: movies.results,
        })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
   ...stuff
}
```

Then in my test i am mocking the result, and setting a property on the response called `success` to true

So, the catch error should not be triggered, however the console.log in the catch block is being logged.

Here is the test:

```
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock')

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup
})

const movies = {
  success: true,
  results: [
    {
      id: 'hi1',
      title: 'title1',
      poster_path: 'gfdsftg'
    },
    {
      id: 'hi2',
      title: 'title2',
      poster_path: 'gfdsftg'
    }
  ]
}

const movie = movies.results[0]

test('<MoviesList />', async  () => {
  fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(movies))
  const {getByTestId, queryByTestId, getAllByTestId} = render(<MoviesList />)

  ...some assertions here that all pass
})
```

Why is the catch block being triggered?

Comment: Take a look at the error that is caught. It'll likely tell you exactly what failed. It doesn't have to be caused by the fetch.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the post with the eror, its a network request failed., butI am faking a correct response, or at least that's what I think its doing, any tips?